# Literature to this nonlinear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am interested in the following nonlinear PDE for a function $u:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$, $d=2,3$:

$$
-\Delta \phi(u) = 0,
$$

where $\phi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous, strictly increasing function with $\phi(\pm \infty) = \pm \infty$ and $\phi(0)=0$, e.g. $\phi(u) = |u|^{m-1} u$.

Computing the Laplacian (for $d=2$) results in

$$
            \Delta(\phi(u)) = \nabla \cdot \nabla \phi(u) = \nabla \cdot (\phi'(u) \nabla u) = (\phi'(u) u_x)_x + (\phi'(u) u_y)_y \\
            = \phi''(u) u_x u_x + \phi'(u) u_{xx} + \phi''(u) u_y u_y + \phi'(u) u_{yy} \\
            = \phi''(u) |\nabla u|^2 + \phi'(u) \Delta u. 
$$
With this we can rewrite the PDE as

$$
F(u,\nabla u, \Delta u) = 0,
$$
for $F(u,\nabla u, \Delta u):= -\phi''(u) |\nabla u|^2 - \phi'(u) \Delta u$.

Can anyone help me with literature about existence and uniqueness of (weak) solutions to a nonlinear PDE of this type or something similar?

Thank you very much in advance!

Kind regards,
Frank

Comment: A quasilinear elliptic problem? https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1938-043-01/S0002-9947-1938-1501936-8/S0002-9947-1938-1501936-8.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much! That's the class of PDE I was looking for.